# How remove ' ' in python, turning string to list or tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I am wondering if there is any idea to remove **' '** from tuple items in the passed and get the needed as below :

```
passed = (('XCl', 'XNa', 'Xwater'), 'WwaterNaCl', 'UwaterNaCl', 'VwaterNaCl', 'BNaCl')

needed = ((XCl, XNa, Xwater), WwaterNaCl, UwaterNaCl, VwaterNaCl, BNaCl)
```

what I 'm getting in my code are two lists:

```
vars = ['XCl', 'XNa', 'Xwater']
params = ['WwaterNaCl', 'UwaterNaCl', 'VwaterNaCl', 'BNaCl']
```

then the following are made:

```
[['XCl', 'XNa', 'Xwater'], 'WwaterNaCl', 'UwaterNaCl', 'VwaterNaCl', 'BNaCl']
```

turning to,

```
lam_pars = ((XCl, XNa, Xwater), BNaCl, WwaterNaCl, UwaterNaCl,                   
 VwaterNaCl)
```

and should be passed in lambdify as following:

```
s_p = sp.lambdify(lam_pars, lnfca(), modules=["sympy"])
```

Comment: You want to print it format without quotes?

Comment: Thank for answering, No in fact, I should pass the needed   to lambdify in sympy.

Comment: can you confirm that you want to turn strings to variables ?

Comment: Yes, they will be passed as variable.

Comment: I edited my question perhaps other paths would be possible.

Comment: @user19396094, try `lam_pars = f'(({", ".join(vars)}), {", ".join(params)})'`

Comment: def _lambdifygenerated(^((XCl, XNa, Xwater), WwaterNaCl, UwaterNaCl, VwaterNaCl, BNaCl)):
                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It returns correct print while when passed to lambdify function gives syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom may find it useful, in the following way we can remove the quote and change string type to list or tuple:

```
import sympy as sym
vars = ['XCl', 'XNa', 'Xwater']
params = ['WwaterNaCl', 'UwaterNaCl', 'VwaterNaCl', 'BNaCl']
_symreg_1 = []
_symreg_2 = []
for i in vars:
    _symreg_1 += sym.symbols(i + ',')
print('_symreg_1:', type(_symreg_1), _symreg_1)
for i in params:
    _symreg_2 += sym.symbols(i + ',')
print('_symreg_2:', type(_symreg_2), _symreg_2)
_symreg_2.insert(0, _symreg_1)
print(_symreg_2)


>> _symreg_1: <class 'list'> [XCl, XNa, Xwater]
_symreg_2: <class 'list'> [WwaterNaCl, UwaterNaCl, VwaterNaCl, BNaCl]
[[XCl, XNa, Xwater], WwaterNaCl, UwaterNaCl, VwaterNaCl, BNaCl]
```

this way as list or tuple it can be passed to lambdify